# Why EfficientSU2 in QGAN

Tags: qiskit, resource-request, variational-quantum-algorithms

In Qiskit's [QGAN example](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/machine-learning/tutorials/04_torch_qgan.html),  the parameterised quantum circuit to be trained is the EfficientSU2. I have not found any citation there on the choice of this circuit, and the only justification is that it has a large number of parameters. Why is it thought that it is a useful circuit to encode a probability distribution? Is there some good reference on it?